# Dynamically Concatenate PHP Code

Tags: php, arrays

In this example, I have two arrays. In my actual process I will have 7 arrays, but I'm keeping it simple here.

```
$first = array('2015-05-10', '2015-05-17');
$second = array('2015-05-11','2015-05-18');
```

The following code will merge the two arrays:

```
$merged = array();
$merged = (array_merge($first,$second));
```

In the actual process, anywhere from 1 to 7 arrays could be merged together, but combinations could be different each time. Thus, I want to build a set of 'if' statements to dynamically build the merge statement. Similar to:

```
$dynamicMerge = 'array_merge(';
if($Sunday == '1') {
$dynamicMerge = $dynamicMerge .= '$first' . ',';
}
if($Monday == '1') {
$dynamicMerge = $dynamicMerge .= '$second';
}
$dynamicMerge = $dynamicMerge .= ')';
```

If it were hard-coded like the following, it would print the value of the merged arrays.

```
$merged = (array_merge($first,$second));
print_r($merged);
```

Array
(
    [0] => 2015-05-10
    [1] => 2015-05-17
    [2] => 2015-05-11
    [3] => 2015-05-18
)

However, the following code, created from the dynamic code above does not print out the values.

```
print_r($dynamicMerge);
```

It prints out: array_merge($first,$second)

What needs to be done to the dynamic code for it to print out the "value of the merged array", and not the code to return the array?

Thanks in advance.

Tom

Comment: It looks as though these are 'date ranges'? Can they overlap? What do you actually want as a list of output dates as regards your input date range examples?

Comment: The individual bits of data in each array are individual dates, such as every Saturday in the month of May 2015. A second array may have the dates of every Tuesday in that month. Once I get the arrays merged, the next step will be to sort them by date.

Answer (score 1):

array merge accepts an infinite amount of arrays.

```
$mergedArr = array_merge($arr1, $arr2, $arr3, $arr4, $arr5, $arr6, $arr7);
```

Or if you're thinking of doing it this way ...

```
$mergedArr = [];

if ($monday) {
    $mergedArr = array_merge($mergedArr, $mondayArr);
}

if ($tuesday) {
    $mergedArr = array_merge($mergedArr, $tuesdayArr);
}
```

Comment: it looks like the your second set of code will work to dynamically build the array. It's the code that takes that array and prints it out that I'm having a problem with. Thank you for your code suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You could also merge those arrays thru `call_user_func_array`. First off, gather all the arrays that needed to be merged. After that, invoke the function:

```
// loop days from monday to sunday
$days = array(
    'Sunday' => 'first',
    'Monday' => 'second',
    'Tuesday' => 'third',
    'Wednesday' => 'fourth',
    'Thursday' => 'fifth',
    'Friday' => 'sixth',
    'Saturday' => 'seventh',
);

$arrays = array();
foreach($days as $day => $var) {
    if($$day == 1) {
        $arrays[] = $$var;
    }
}

$result = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $arrays);
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/GbsxAK)

Comment: Ghost you nailed it! Your invoking the function in your 'Sample Output' code is exactly what I needed. Thank you very much! (Unfortunately, my stackoverflow.com rep is a lowly '1' and I can't even up-vote your answer.)

Comment: @user1025900 sure no prob, if any of these answers helped you, you could just accept/check any answer, glad this helped